# Connect to MongoDB with Flutter Web

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, web-applications, flutter-web

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB with a Flutter web app and I keep finding posts on internet about not being possible to do it (only with mobiles app), but I find it kind of strange.

I tried it with a local mongodb (didn't work apparently because of dart:io), but I can't even use a remote MongoDB server hosted...
I also tried with an embedded javascript that had a express+mongodb api server, no luck...

Please is there any way to make it work in Flutter WEB (no mobile) ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you create a RESTful API around your MongoDB, that way you can do all your CRUD operations against Mongo via HTTP requests. Calling a DB directly is not a good practice. You can host a local NodeJS or even Python Flask web service to pull your MongoDB data and expose your HTTP endpoints to your Flutter web app.

Comment: I understand and I think it’s the last option, but is it possible to launch the nodejs rest api from flutter ? Because if not, it means the two apps have to be start separately and that kind of sucks…

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.